# Noether's paper

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Noether's paper:

An integral is invariant under 
$$
y^i = x^i + \Delta x^i , \ \ v^i(y) = u^i + \Delta u^i,
$$
whenever
$$
\int f\left(y,v(y),\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)dy =\int f\left(x,u(x),\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)dx
$$
holds. Fairly intuitive. Noether, later on, states that the integral over $dy$ can be written as

> \begin{equation}
> \int f\left(y,v(y),\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)dy = \int f\left(x,v(x),\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right) \ dx + \int \text{Div}(f\Delta x) \ dx. 
> \end{equation}

The variation in $x$, if it is performed, it induces changes also in
$$
v(y)=v(x+\Delta x)=v(x)+\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x^a}\Delta x^a + \mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2) 
$$
and likewise the $\partial v/\partial y$ terms in the $f$, both of which are missing from the central equation above. Is she using the equations of motion?